# How to assign variable php?

Tags: php, variables

I have a following php function:

```
public function getTrailer()
{
    return $this->model->trailer;
}
```

How to assigned value of **$this->model->trailer** to **$new** variable. And can you explain me what **$this->model->trailer** means, please ?

Thanks !

Comment: This link should help you understand PHP OOP logic: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php

Comment: `->` accesses a class property or method.

Comment: Yeah, in your case you have property $model in your class, who is an object with probably public access to property trailer?

Comment: @ailvenge, sorry but I don't understand your mean because I am poor about programming

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To assigned the value to a new variable do this:**`$newVar = $this->model->trailer;`**

The meaning of `$this->model->trailer` is that is taking the value that are inside of the structure. Is looking what are inside `$this`, and inside the `model` and inside of `trailer` and taking the value.